# Using Ids from temp table to update actual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am selecting two values into a temp table.
After I have done this, I want to do an update, to one of the tables I select from, on all the Id's that I just selected into my temp table.
How do I do this?

It sounds pretty simple I just can't really figure out where to begin.
I tried

```
update table set value = @tempTable.value where id = @temptable.id
```

but of course that didn't work.
I can, of course, do a select that gives me the update commands, for each entry in the temp table, but I would very much like to do this, in one process instead of having to execute the update commands afterwards.

Do I need to make some foreach from the temp table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
update tab 
set value = tt.value 
from @temptable tt
where tab.id = tt.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
UPDATE t 
SET value = t2.value 
FROM [table] t
JOIN @temptable t2 ON t.id = t2.id
```